# Weight Rigging Different for Mesh

Tags: rigging

Thank you in advance to anyone who assists me with this, I have been stuck on this problem for two days now. I have the same bone armature along with identical hand meshes, one just mirrored. When I automatically weight the objects the left hand works perfectly while the right hand is attached to multiple fingers.

I tried searching for ways to fix this without manually weighing every finger as its very tedious, unfortunately I couldn't find a post with a way to fix this.

Left Hand that is working correctly:
[ https://gyazo.com/4b0aa45edfefcf9a3d083ab616887887 ]

Right Hand, which is copy, pasted and mirrored to the correct direction:
[ https://gyazo.com/ec044e1b62b559bcd2f65a68759bc04a ]

Here are the weights. Once again, an exact copy and paste. Yet automatic weight caught different sections of the hand.

Left Hand

[image: Left Hand Weight]

Right Hand
[image: Right Hand Weight]

Comment: Check (and fix) your normals.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Nathan for mentioning normals. [ https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/24636/nathan ]

For anyone who may have this problem, you select your mesh and recalculate inside normals.

I used this video for reference [ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clzstqtN6YQ ]